# How can I use jquery variable from html template in separate js file appended to this html template?

Tags: jquery, django

How to use variable MEDIA_URL in my my.js?

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        var MEDIA_URL = '{{ MEDIA_URL }}'
    })
</script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}/my.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to define MEDIA_URL in the document ready call just do:

```
<script>
var MEDIA_URL = '{{ MEDIA_URL }}'
</script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}/my.js"></script>
```